# Aggregate totals by Keys in a document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a mapreduce function I want to write in mongoDB to count how many times a character has been played with. The relevant part from my json looks like this:

```
"playerInfo": {
"Player 1": {
  "info":{
          "characterId":17
         }
       },
"Player 2": {
      "info":{
              "characterId":20
             }
       }
}
```

I want to count how many times every "characterId" persists in my documents, there are 10 players, from player 1 to player 10.

Two questions:

1. How do I use mapreduce in mongo when I have a number as a part of my key.

2. How do I concatinate string in mapreduce so the code that is shown lower can be correct?

```
db.LoL.mapReduce( function() 
                    {
                        for (var i in this.playerInfo)
                        {
                            emit(this.playerInfo.'Player '+(i).info.characterId, 1);
                        }

                    },
                  function(keys, values) {
                    return Array.sum(values)
                  }, {out: { merge: "map_reduce_example5" } } )
```

Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are really a couple of things wrong with the structure here and you really "should" change it

The `mapReduce` is pretty simple since you can just iterate the key names via `Object.keys()`

```
db.LoL.mapReduce(
  function() {
    Object.keys(this.playerInfo).forEach(function(key) {
      emit({ "player": key, "characterId": this.playerInfo[key].info.characterId },  1)
    })
  },
  function(values) { return Array.sum(values) },
  { 
    "query": { "playerInfo": { "$exists": true } }
    "out": { "inline": 1 }
  }
)
```

If you instead change the data format to use an array, and properties with values instead of named keys:

```
{
  "playerInfo": [
    { "player": "Player 1", "characterId": 17 },
    { "player": "Player 2", "characterId": 20 }
  ]
}
```

Then the `.aggregate()` method is much faster in processing this, and returns a cursor for large result sets:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$playerInfo" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$playerInfo",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

With MongoDB 3.4 and greater you can even use on your present structure

```
db.LoL.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "playerInfo": { "$objectToArray": "$playerInfo" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$playerInfo" },
  { "$group": {
     "_id": {
       "player": "$playerInfo.k", 
       "characterId": "$playerInfo.v.info.characterId"
     },
     "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

Which is basically the same as the mapReduce, only a lot faster due to the native operators used as opposed to JavaScript evaluation, which runs much slower.